# Как поставить блок вниз страницы, не закрепляя его?

Tags: css

Собственно как?

Пытаюсь закрепить блок с помощью position значением  fixed, но когда размер окна изменяется (на меньший, чем размер двух блоков - верхнего и нижнего, который нужно закрепить), этот блок (нижний) наезжает на верхний блок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

z-index у верхнего блока должен быть больше, чем у нижнего.

Подробнее: http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index

Comment: Проблема в том, что верхний блок не фиксирован, и имеет `position: inherit`

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, скриншоты

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Можно перед фиксированным блоком создать div и регулировать пространство при помощи height. Это как вариант.

Comment: Например? Можете продемонстрировать?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="height: 50px"></div>
<div class="footer-fixed"></div>
```

Инлайновый стиль замените на обычный.